# Android is not working with SQLite Cursor?? Only with cursor.getColumnIndex(..)

Tags: android, sqlite

Look at the both gif's i just debug my code after i got a ticket from my QM
Then i saw that the code is working really strange. 
I did not change any code behind only in this function and it's working like expected and you can see it in the second picture.

This is also NOT only in debug mode... the Bug that was reported by my QM comes from a release version.

my code is working now but can anyone explain me THAT crazy behavior?

thank you

UPDATE:
the question is not about "How can i get values from the cursor" the Question is about: 
**WHY the program flow is like crazy if i use columnIDX**

[image: this is the bad one]
[image: this is the good one]

Comment: Have you changed your select query ? 
Instead of using columnIndex, use column name while getting data from cursor.

Comment: as u can see in the second pic ... i use the column names... but i did NOT change the query!!

Comment: Ok, maybe it has something to do with sqlite db version in your client mobile. Does your app has support for devices with api level 8 ?

Comment: my minSdkVersion = 17 and the device where i check this was API 22